# SAS - comparing variable contents and flagging variations

Tags: performance, sas, duplicates, compare

I've received a flattened file that preserves information about duplicate ID records in additional variables, rather than additional records.

For example, the dataset below:

```
ResID   VarA   VarB
XAB2    Red    13
XAB2    Ylw    13
BGH3    Grn    14
FHT1    Prp    13
XAB2    Blu    13
```

Got turned in to this:

```
ResID   VarA_1   VarA_2   VarA_3   VarB_1   VarB_2   VarB_3
XAB2    Red      Ylw      Blu      13       13       13
BGH3    Grn                        14
FHT1    Prp                        13
```

As you can see, all the variables associated with ID "XAB2" were flattened into one record, so all the information could be preserved but the dataset could still be handled as a person-level file.

This is cool. But now I need to reconcile the discrepancies between the dups.

I currently plan to write a series of very boring if/else if statements in a data step, like:

```
     if VarA_2 NE " " and VarA_2 EQ VarA_1 then FLAG_VarA_dup = 0;
else if VarA_2 NE " " and VarA_2 NE VarA_1 then FLAG_VarA_dup = 1;
else if VarA_3 NE " " and VarA_3 EQ VarA_2 then FLAG_VarA_dup = 0;
else if VarA_3 NE " " and VarA_3 NE VarA_2 then FLAG_VarA_dup = 1;

/*...etc. for all VarB occurrences, and all other variables in my very wide DS*/
```

Once I've flagged the variables within which the dups live, then I can compare the relevant variables and make decisions about what to keep or dig deeper on. But I can't help but think there's a much more elegant or efficient way to do this. I'd love to learn a thing or two here.

Any suggestions for a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know if VarA_# has any values other than the first in it, then you can use `tranwrd` and `countw` to verify this.  Basically, ask SAS to make your `VarA_#` set into a single string, delimited by a delimiter of your choice, then use `tranwrd` to convert all copies of your first variable's value to missing.  Then count the number of words in the remaining string - 0 means you have only that first value, 1 or higher means you have some different values.

```
data have;
  infile datalines truncover;
  input ResID   $ VarA_1   $ VarA_2   $ VarA_3   $ VarB_1   VarB_2   VarB_3;
datalines;
XAB2    Red      Ylw      Blu      13       13       13
BGH3    Grn       Grn       .         14       14
FHT1    Prp        .       .         13
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  array varA_[3];
  count_a = countw(catx(' ',of varA_[*]));
  count_a_diff = countw(tranwrd(catx(' ',of VarA_[*]),trim(varA_1),' '));
run;
```

Comment: To avoid matching parts of a word you need add delimiters to both arguments in the TRANWRD() function call. In spite of its name TRANWRD() doesn't know what a word is.

Comment: @Tom That's a good point, if partial word matching is possible in the data.  I'm not going to address that in the answer for the moment, if you want to do so please feel free (in your own answer or above).